# I'm trying to open a program using Python. second arg needs to have quotes removed

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a program in python and arg1 needs to have the quotes removed.

Python code:

```
strt_rpt ='C:\\PROGRAM FILES\\GOM\\2018\\BIN\\gom_inspect'  
arg1 = 'pro -eval'
process = subprocess.Popen([strt_rpt, arg1.replace("''", '')], shell = True)
```

My question is how do I strip the quotes off arg1 ".replace" is not working?

Thank You 
For any help

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: C:  is the location of the program on my computer, that I'm writing the code.  D: is location on the computer, where program will be used.

Comment: my python code errors on arg1,  when I pass arg1 it needs to be stripped of quotes.

Comment: Dear Nick, your question is unclear. Please, consider to edit your question to include what is your goal, what you did try and what error you got.

Comment: I'm trying to execute this command:             ( 'C:\\PROGRAM FILES\\GOM\\2018\\BIN\\gom_inspect'  pro -eval ) and pro -eval  can not have any quotes.   Thanks

Comment: I tried different ways of passing arg1 and I get a syntax error or an error when loading program. if I open a command prompt and type my command or execute my vb code the program will load.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question? Besides, if vb.net works, why the switch to Python?

Comment: I don't see your problem. You set `arg1 = 'pro -eval'`. Now `arg1` doesn't have any quotes.

Comment: I would like to keep all my code in one language. second I would like to learn why I can not get this to work.

Comment: strt_rpt ='C:\\PROGRAM FILES\\GOM\\2018\\BIN\\gom_inspect'            
arg1 = 'pro -eval'
print([strt_rpt, arg1.replace('""', "")])   =   ['C:\\PROGRAM FILES\\GOM\\2018\\BIN\\gom_inspect', 'pro -eval']  quotes are still there.

Comment: You're looking at the representation of the list, not at the content of the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print on the screen using the `print` function, python always adds quotes to tell you that is printing a string. But if in the code you have `arg1 = 'pro -eval'` the string itself does not contain any quote. You do not need to replace anything.

But try to use subprocess like this:

```
arg1 = 'pro'
arg2 = '-eval'
process = subprocess.Popen([strt_rpt, arg1, arg2])
```

I think is likely that your program receives `pro -eval` as a single argument, when they should be two separate arguments. Each element of the argument list should be one argument only. So do not put spaces inside them unless you really want to pass an argument with a space.

Also I don't think you need the shell argument set to True in this case. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html):

> If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the
>   shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the
>   enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want
>   convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes,
>   filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~
>   to a user’s home directory.

Which does not seem your case. This way you can also avoid to escape your backslashes in `strt_rpt`.

Comment: You're welcome. You might consider to accept the answer if it was helpful.